# Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker in EditorTemplate

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, mvc-editor-templates

Created an Editor Template to dynamically create time slots. Now I am unable to select the time with datetimepicker. Code below. The following code works when apart of the main view. Is it possible to use datetimepicker in an editortemplate?

```
@model Testing.Models.TimeSlot

<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt"), @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100px"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15).ToString("hh:mm tt"), @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100px" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#StartTime').datetimepicker({

            format: 'LT',
            showClose: true,
            showClear: true,
            toolbarPlacement: 'top',
            stepping: 15,
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#EndTime').datetimepicker({

            format: 'LT',
            showClose: true,
            showClear: true,
            toolbarPlacement: 'top',
            stepping: 15
        });
    });
    $('#StartTime').removeAttr("data-val-date");
    $('#EndTime').removeAttr("data-val-date");
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have editor templates for `DateTime` or `DateTime?` types? If not, using EditorFor probably isn't any more useful than simply using TextBoxFor, which [does have an overload for a format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/ee834950(v=vs.118)#inputextensionstextboxfortmodeltproperty-method-htmlhelpertmodelexpressionfunctmodeltpropertystringidictionarystringobject)

Comment: They have DateTime?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sections are not supported in partials, and your scripts are never included in the html returned to the client. In any case, scripts should never be in partials (which is what an `EditorTemplate` is) - you are generating inline scripts, making it harder to debug and risk including multiple instances of the scripts.

Delete the `@section Scripts{ ... }` code from your `EditorTemplate` and move it to the main view or its layout. To make this a bit more flexible, I recommend you give the inputs a class name, and use that as a jQuery selector, rather that referring to each individual `id` (and therefore only one script is required).

In addition, you should never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. The methods correctly generate the `value` from `ModelState`, `ViewData` and finally the model property in that order, and by setting the `value` attribute, you are screwing up model binding. Instead, set the values in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.

Your code to generate the datepicker should be just

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" } })
```

or more simply

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" })
```

and you can then style the width

```
.datetimepicker {
    width: 100px;
}
```

and the the script in the view or layout will be just

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',
    showClose: true,
    showClear: true,
    toolbarPlacement: 'top',
    stepping: 15,
});
```

Its also not clear why you want to attempt to remove client side validation using `.removeAttr("data-val-date")`, and doing so suggests a problem with your design. It also appears that you want to select a time only, in which case your property should be `TimeSpan`.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Also the removeAttr is nolonger used. There was an issue where it required a date and time, but only being time. Has since been fixed. Thanks for going the extra mile.